# D3 axis not show

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new go D3.js. I saw a code for stacked bar from the following link.

https://gist.github.com/mstanaland/6100713

The axises are not shown.

Thanks!

Comment: The axis are shown. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x14O7ZVGIx2LwQJwEjKQ?p=preview)

Comment: the lines of axis are not shown in this code. I need that solid line axis. The text is shown in it which I already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this style

```
path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}
```

And add this

```
path.domain {
  stroke: red;
}
```